# Re-rander the current route component

Tags: reactjs, redux

when ever user refreshed page, page is disconnect and user had to entry the user-id and password again. instead app should able to take previously entered values and re-login itself.

Eg:- https://hi.com/abc/xyz

Answer (score 0):

if your login APIs are authenticated, you can check whether it s authenticated then redirect into home page, if not do it!!!!